# How to post json with Postman to Azure Functions?

Tags: azure-functions, postman

1. I can successfully perform Get with postman with url and get input value logged correctly (line 25). http://localhost:7071/api/orchestrators/CalculateOrchestrator?jsoninput=helloworld
2. However I cannot get Post value logged. It is displayd "jsonInput = 'None'". Is it issue with Postman or with Function code? Function bindings are for both Get and Post.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with your code. Neither postman nor function binding issue.
You are reading from the query params (line 18).
You should read it from the request body.

```
jsonString = req.get_body().decode(encoding='utf-8')
```

Please check for decoding bytes to object. `get_body()` returns bytes.